# Unable to create Azure Key Vault secret inside our Microsoft Partner centre. "The operation "Set" is not enabled in this key vault's access policy."

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-security

We are managing our customers' azure subscriptions using Microsoft Partner Centre >> and using a username I create a new Azure Vault for a customer>> but when I tried to create a new Secret inside the Azure Vault , I got this error:-

> The operation "Set" is not enabled in this key vault's access policy.

[image]

now when I access the Key Vault >> Access Policy >> I am unable to add the login username which I used to create the Key Vault inside the Key Vault access policy, where I am only able to add the office 365 admin:-

[image]

so any advice why i am able to create a new Key Vault, while i am unable to add Secrets inside it?

Comment: The default access policy is the current user when you create a Key vault. https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0jYm.png Have you checked this when creating it?

Comment: @PamelaPeng can you advice more on this please?

Comment: For me, 1) create a key vault with userA, and add the required permissions in access policy tab. 2) create a secret with userA. That's all.

Comment: When you're trying to create the secret, does the user that you're logged in as have an RBAC role for the key vault that is at least "Contributor"?

Comment: @MattSmall no the user i created the Key vault using it, can not be defined inside the RBAC role for the key valut.. so this is quite confusing

Comment: I think you should open a support case for this.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the Key vault, you should add the CSP access policy rather than normal access policy.

[image]

After you click on it, you can specify CSP security group (it has shown the steps to get the group id).

[image]

Then the CSP user can create secret in this key vault after it's created.