# Azure Key Vault The operation "List" is not enabled in this key vault's access policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I want to add secrets to the key vault that my Azure ML service created.

Despite adding myself (first for get+list secrets, and then) all keys, secrets and certificates options in the access policies, I am still unable to list any keys, secrets or certificates, nor create any.

I added myself using the same e-mail login.
I looked at tutorials and videos, but unfortunately many are years old and despite following the step, it remains inaccessible.

I also checked [Unable to create Azure Key Vault secret inside our Microsoft Partner centre. "The operation "Set" is not enabled in this key vault's access policy."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67377054/unable-to-create-azure-key-vault-secret-inside-our-microsoft-partner-centre-th) but I do not see any CSP options.

Is it because it is a key vault created when Azure ML was created with an option implicitly selected that no additional secrets can be made?

//edit

After comment:
it looks exactly like what you have. All keys/secrets/certificates added.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you include [Access policies](https://i.imgur.com/P2qBWvm.png) and [Access configuration](https://i.imgur.com/e4JqL2z.png) snips of your key vault by editing your question?

Comment: It looks exactly like that.

Comment: I am having exact same issue. I'll watch this ticket.

Answer (score 3):

Note that, key vault created by Azure ML service contains access policies assigned to **only ML workspace** (Application type) by default like below:

[image]

When I tried to add secrets to the key vault, I too got **same error** as user account does not have any vault access policy assigned:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you need to create another vault **access policy** by adding required permissions and assign it to signed-in **user account**:

[image]

After assigning access policy to the **signed-in** user account, it will appear like below:

[image]

When I tried to **add secrets** to the key vault again, secret added successfully like this:

[image]

In your case, check whether you assigned vault access policy to **signed-in user account** or not.

*If still the error persists, try to create **Azure support request** with Microsoft.*

Comment: Are you saying that it's possible to assign access to a user that is NOT signed in?  Kinda confused.   I currently am experiencing this issue.  Hard to figure out. I might need to create a brand new key vault to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the process that Sridevi nicely explained above. At first it didn't work, because I selected items in the Application tab. The second time I created access policy and skipped the Application tab and it worked.
[image]